# SELECT last entry for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a TABLE user_orders with fields -->

- order_id int(10),
- user_id int(10),
- order_payment_id int(10)
- order_created int(10)

I want to find the last order_payment_id used for each user_id. I try

```
SELECT order_payment_id, user_id , MAX(order_id) as lastone
FROM user_orders 
GROUP BY user_id;
```

but the result is wrong

Answer (score 6):

You can use a self-join to filter out the relevant data

```
SELECT o1.*
FROM user_orders o1
JOIN
(
   SELECT user_id, MAX(order_created) as lastone 
   FROM user_orders
   GROUP BY user_id
) o2 on o1.user_id = o2.user_id 
    and o1.order_created = o2.lastone
GROUP BY o1.user_id
```

Comment: if `order_created` is a unique field (i.e. primary index), `on o1.user_id = o2.user_id` can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

The `MAX` should be in the `WHERE` clause, or it will select the maximum `order_id` for the whole table.

```
SELECT order_payment_id, user_id ,order_id as lastone
FROM user_orders u1
WHERE  u1.order_id = (SELECT MAX(order_id)
                      FROM user_orders u2
                      WHERE u1.user_id = u2.user_id);
```

Using this query, you can get rid of the `GROUP BY` except if `order_id` is not unique.

That way you'll get the last order associated with the user.

Answer (score 0):

The general GROUP BY rule is:
*If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.*

```
SELECT order_payment_id, user_id , order_id as lastone
FROM user_orders uo
WHERE order_id = (select MAX(order_id) from user_orders
                  where user_id = uo.user_id)
```